# Refresh partial view content when submit button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed view, which has a form in which I put one field showtime when the submit button is clicked I want to save the entry into database also display that entry along with other entries on the database inside the  partial view I put on the main view . When the Index action method is called the Main view is rendered .I want to update the Partial view when a new entry is saved without reloading the whole page ,just refresh the partial page.

Here is my view :

```
@model Bookmany.Admin.Models.Theater.TheaterShowTimeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Theater showTimes / BookMany";
 }

<h3>Theater ShowTimes</h3>
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TheaterID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TheaterID, Model.AvailableTheaters)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TheaterID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShowTimeName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ShowTimeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShowTimeName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
  @Html.Partial("_TheaterShowTimeList", Model.TheaterShowTimeList)
</div>
```

Here is my partial view :

```
@model IEnumerable<Bookmany.Core.Domain.TheaterShowTime>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Theater Name
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShowTimeName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Theater.TheaterName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TheaterShowTimeID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TheaterShowTimeID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TheaterShowTimeID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My action method :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TheaterShowTimeViewModel();

        //Bind Theater dropdown with selected value
        model.AvailableTheaters = GetTheaters();
        model.TheaterShowTimeList = _theaterShowTimeService.GetAllTheaterShowTime();
        return View(model);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TheaterShowTimeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            InsertOrUpdateTheaterShowTime(model);
            model.TheaterShowTimeList=_theaterShowTimeService.GetAllTheaterShowTime();
            return PartialView("_TheaterShowTimeList", model.TheaterShowTimeList);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

my problems :

when I enter one value in the field and submit the form ,the entry saved now the partial view is only returned with the updated list

I want to update the partial view without reloading the whole page how do achieve that?

Comment: Your need to submit the form using ajax (not a normal submit) and return a partial view that can be added to the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke , I submit the form as :using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "TheaterShowTime", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "theaterShowList" }
))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @* my controls goes hre *@} but this will still return the partial view only what I need to change in the action

Comment: The code in you question shows `Html.BeginForm()` not `Ajax.BeginForm()` so not sure what your saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Stephen Muecke  said I posted the form using ajax when the submit button clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#ShowTimeName').val("");
                $('#theaterShowList').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
  });
 });
</script>
```

In my action method which returns the partial view :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TheaterShowTimeViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            InsertOrUpdateTheaterShowTime(model);
            model.TheaterShowTimeList=_theaterShowTimeService.GetAllTheaterShowTime();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.TheaterID });
            //return Json(model.TheaterShowTimeList);
            return PartialView("_TheaterShowTimeList", model.TheaterShowTimeList);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

this resolved my issue

Comment: The script doesn't work correctly for me. The Action reloads the hole page and renders just the Partial View. Do you have an idea why happens this? Thanks!